# format windows recovery partition in hard drive externally

Tags: boot, windows-vista, partitioning, external-hard-drive, system-reserved-partition

I want to format a disk from my other laptop.  I have an external drive reader and when I attempt to format the disk, it only formats the main partition but the recovery sector remains intact. I am attempting to install Ubuntu on the laptop.

What should I do to remove it?

Comment: How did you format it? With what software?

Comment: use disk manager and delete each partition by hand yourself.

Comment: I can format the main partition successfully by the recovery partition wont go. gparted fails and windows Disk Management wont show any options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are directions for force-removing a recovery partition.

1. Open a command prompt as administrator.
2. Run Diskpart application by typing **`Diskpart`** in the command prompt.
3. In the “Diskpart" prompt, enter **`rescan`** command and press Enter key to re-scan all partitions, volumes and drives available.
4. Then type in **`list disk`** and press Enter key to show all hard disk drive available.
5. Select the disk that contains the partition you want to remove. In your case, this may be disk 1 or more, your primary drive is probably Disk 0--the numbering is the same as in Disk Management. So the command could be:**`Select disk 1`** .  Triple check you are entering the right disk.
6. Type **`list partition`** and press Enter key to show all partitions in the disk selected.
7. Select the partition that wanted to be deleted by using the following command, followed by Enter key:  **`Select partition x`**  Where x is the number of the recovery partition to be removed. Be careful with the number of this partition, as entering the wrong number will be a bad thing.
8. Finally, type in **`delete partition override`** and press Enter key.